# Why does the sizeof a class give different output in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, sizeof

According to the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof),

> When applied to a reference type, the result is the size of the
> referenced type.

But in the following program, compiler is giving different output.

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

class A 
{
    private:
        char ch;
        const char &ref = ch;
};

int main()
{
    cout<<sizeof(A)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
16
```

Here `ch` is of a character type and the reference is also of type character. So output would be 2 bytes instead of 16 bytes.

Online compiler: [GDB](https://onlinegdb.com/1NwMXqItl)

Comment: *"When applied to a reference type"* - You are not applying it to a reference type.

Comment: The size of a class object is not simply the size of each member object tallied up.

Comment: To add to what @Eljay said, data is usually allocated in chunks that depend on your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you're asking for the size of the object, not of the reference type itself.

`sizeof(A::ref)` will equal `1`:

```cpp
class A 
{
    public:
        char ch;
        const char &ref = ch;
};

int main()
{
    cout<<sizeof(A::ref)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The object size is `16` because:

1. The actual size taken up by the reference type inside the object is equal to the size of a pointer (`8` in this case).
2. Because the [object alignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object) has increased to `8` due to the reference type, the `char` now also takes up `8` bytes even though it only really uses `1` byte of that space.

I.e. If you were to change `char ch` to `char ch[8]`, `sizeof(A)` would still equal `16`:

```cpp
class A 
{
    private:
        char ch[8];
        const char &ref = ch[0];
};

int main()
{
    cout<<sizeof(A)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```